# How remove label from cluster react-google-maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I use library react-google-maps [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps)

How can I remove label from cluster? I don't want to show number of internal markers

Answer (score 0):

As per the Google Doc For the **MarkerClusterer** below styles are available

[image]

otherwise you can remove label with `text-indent: 100%` style property.

There is also one method called `setStyles` but it only supports above styles.

Doc Link: [Docs](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html)